# Charting - avoid distortion of column series when large periods are queried

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts

Is there a way when one can avoid distortion of the width and overlapping of column series when one queries large time intervals? When a smaller amount of days are queried then columns look fine. When the interval is increased, the columns look with different width from each other. If you further increase the period then in some parts of the chart area there is overlapping. Finally all columns overlap in one single shape. In all cases following property is set like following:

```
ch.Series(0).CustomProperties = "PointWidth = 0.6"
```

I will depict the problem with examples below.

1. Small amount of days - all is fine

[image]

[image]

2. Bigger number of days - width is already different (difference from previous charts is that after a certain amount of days I remove the borderline of columns)

[image]

[image]

3. Even greater period - now in some parts of chart there is overlapping.

[image]

[image]

4. Extending further the period and all columns are overlapping.

[image]

[image]

I guess full overlapping cannot be avoided and is generally fine. My issue is with partial overlapping (section 3) and when columns are with different width, because then charts don't look good.

Comment: IMO, when you're getting to that sort of resolution on graphs, perhaps it might be time to reconsider how your representing the data and if a bar chart is still appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing once and then I simply calculated what is the duration of one horizonal pixel (say: I have 1000 pixel width and that represents 30 days then one pixel is 43.2 minutes) and then I just accumulated the data according to a certain logic (maximum value or average) over each of these 43.2 minutes and used these accumulated data for the charts.